# PHPUnit code coverage for abstract class at 0% even though it's clearly tested

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd, abstract-class

Writing a PHP package here, TDD with PhpUnit 4+.

Writing tests for all my regular classes works fine, and they're covered in the report. But when I test the mock of an abstract class, even though the test clearly runs through the method (it fails if I fail to implement it, or if I put some breakpoints in there), the code coverage is 0%.

I've extracted the offending code into a repo [here](https://github.com/Swader/phpunit-oddity), if you'd like to give it a whirl. All you need to do is clone, composer install, and run phpunit, it's all configured.

This is being run on a Vagrant box, so an isolated environment that has nothing in particular to do with my PHP version or available extensions, and was tested by [other people](https://twitter.com/enygma/status/557203249141256192), too, on their installations, producing the same results.

The abstract class being tested is [here](https://github.com/Swader/phpunit-oddity/blob/master/src/abstracts/Api.php), while its test can be seen [here](https://github.com/Swader/phpunit-oddity/blob/master/tests/abstracts/ApiTest.php).

Any hints on what I may be doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Okay, so, as an added explanation, see comments on the accepted answer below, and Jordi's tweets [here](https://twitter.com/seldaek/status/557228384577945600). Basically, for perf reasons, Composer's autoloader just follows the case of the filesystem it's on, so it's best if one uses the same case on the folders as in the class names. If your namespace is uppercase, your folder should be, too. This still leaves open the question about why it actually managed to *read and run* the class' method, but didn't mark it as covered, so if you have any insight into that, please leave a comment or a more complete answer, and I'll re-accept that one.

Edit 2:

Additional sensible explanation by dstockto from IRC:

> I believe the issue is because when phpunit is collecting the code coverage information, it's in PHP arrays. The keys are case sensitive and so even though you have covered that, the coverage was for a differently cased file which PHPunit doesn't match up to the files that were loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it to work and Coverage is 100%. :-) The problem was this:

```
$ phpunit --verbose --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php
PHPUnit 4.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/ren/tmp/phpunit-oddity/phpunit.xml.dist

E

Time: 151 ms, Memory: 3.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Swader\Diffbot\Test\ApiTest::testSetTimeout
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException: Class "Swader\Diffbot\Abstracts\Api" does not exist.
```

Debugging has shown that the real problem is the case-insensitive filesystem on your host. Vagrant runs Linux. Directory `abstracts` is not the same as `Abstracts`. PhpUnit on Linux cannot find the class it's looking for.

Comment: I am not getting your results with the verbose flag activated. Furthermore, if I break the setTimeout method, the tests will break too - so obviously PhpUnit does find the class, and does instantiate it.

Comment: Well, I have a coverage of 100% on the `src` directory after I renamed `abstracts` to `Abstracts`. Did you try renaming the directory? Plus PSR-4 specification states that "All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion". So obviously you have inconsistent class / directory naming.

Comment: Well color me flabbergasted, it worked, thanks! Now, this makes absolutely no sense to me, I would *love* to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Did you run PhpUnit from PhpStorm on Windows?

Comment: Nope. From within the Vagrant box. I only run PhpStorm on Windows - everything else happens in the VM. It is unclear to me why it is even trying to find the class in a folder with the upperclass A, I thought composer's autoloader is forced into case insensitivity.

Comment: What's the exact command you executed? Did you execute in the terminal of the VM or did you configure remote PHP interpreter and executed remote PhpUnit from PhpStorm?

Comment: I run literally everything from within the VM, through a terminal. No tasks are being run from PhpStorm. The command is, literally, `php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --verbose`, nothing more.

Comment: When I ran `vendor/bin/phpunit` without any arguments it could not find the class because I did not specify where composer autoloader is located. It is certainly is not configured in the phpunit.xml.dist . So the question is then how does your PhpUnit loads the class?

Comment: But it is: https://github.com/Swader/phpunit-oddity/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist#L2 - notice that my command doesn't need params. Why is the bin/phpunit different from the one deep inside vendor?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. The one in `vendor/bin` is just a symlink so that should make no difference. The reason it did not find the class is then again because of the case-insensitive directory naming.